# beforeShowForm jqgrid in dynamic form

Tags: jqgrid

```
 {edit:true,add:true,del:false,search:false,refresh:true,view:false} ,
 // edit option
 {  
     beforeShowForm: function(formID) {    
         //alert("TESTALERT");
         jQuery('#tr_b_summe_cvvp', formID).show();
         jQuery('#tr_b_summe_lsv', formID).show(); 
         jQuery('#buchung', formID).click(function() {
             var index = $(this)[0].selectedIndex;
             if (index == 1)      {   jQuery('#tr_b_summe_lsv',  formID).hide();  }
             else if (index == 2) {   jQuery('#tr_b_summe_cvvp', formID).hide();  }
             else if (index == 3) {   jQuery('#tr_b_summe_cvvp', formID).show();  }
             else if (index == 4) {   jQuery('#tr_b_summe_lsv',  formID).show();  }
         });                            
     }
},
```

I want to make a "dynamic" form with jqgrid. When alert() is in use, the form works well,
if not the dynamic change of rows only work in the second attempt

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to use [recreateForm:true](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#properties) option. In my opinion the setting should be default option of the jqGrid form editing.

The problem is that with the default settings `recreateForm:false` jqGrid create the form **only once**, so only at the first time the function `beforeShowForm` will be called. Moreover if you use both Add and Edit forms **only one form** for both dialogs will be created. Then the dialog will be only hide or shown. It makes some very strange effects. So I strictly recommend all to always to use `recreateForm:true` option.

Comment: because of your suggestion, i have default to recreateform - true.  Is there anyway to still cache info in dataUrl to avoid having to reload that data every time you edit a row?

Comment: @leora: I posted my answer on your question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21901410/315935).