# When using jqgrid, is there anyway to have recreateForm: true but also cache dataUrl?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, caching, jqgrid

I have the following columns using jqGrid (simplified)

```
  { name: "PMOPerson", index: "PMOPerson", width: 250, editable: true, edittype: "select", editoptions: { dataUrl: "/Person/GetSelectData" }, editrules: { required: false} },

  { name: "HeadDisplayName", index: "HeadDisplayName", width: 150, editable: false },
```

when i go to edit a row by bringing up the edit dialog, it take 10 seconds for the PMOPerson dropdown to be populated.  This is the case even after i have already loaded it once before and i assume that is because i have recreateForm: true below

```
  addButton({
    caption: "",
    title: "Edit Selected Team",
    buttonicon: 'ui-icon-pencil',
    onClickButton: function () {
        var id = $("#grid").getGridParam("selrow");
        if (id) {

            jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('editGridRow', id,
                    { url: '/OrganisationalUnit/Update', afterSubmit: function (response, postdata) {
                        var responseJson = $.parseJSON(response.responseText);
                        return HandleJqGridResponse(responseJson);
                    },
                        height: 380, width: "auto", recreateForm: true, closeAfterEdit: true,
                        closeOnEscape: true, reloadAfterSubmit: true
                    });
        }
    },
    position: "second"
});
```

I am trying to figure out if there is a way I can have both recreateform: true but still also cache the list of items in dataUrl to avoid going back to the server each time I edit a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered on very close questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12190912/315935) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21884265/315935). In other words you can either use caching options of HTTP header or to use `editoptions.value` instead of `editoptions.dataUrl`.

I described in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19427444/315935) and this two previous one ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21157272/315935) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17410568/315935)) how one can set `editoptions.value` dynamically inside of `beforeProcessing` callback. One need extend the responses from the server used to fill the grid with additional information (with the data like the data returned from  `editoptions.dataUrl`). In my opinion it implements the best compromis between caching of `editoptions.dataUrl` data and refreshing of the data by reloading of the grid. One can still hold cached `editoptions.dataUrl` data *on the server side*.

Alternatively one can use more simple way where one makes *manual* Ajax request to `editoptions.dataUrl` once after creating of the grid and one can set `editoptions.value` inside of `success` (`done`) callback of the Ajax request. The code will be about the following

```js
// create grid
$("#grid").jqGrid({
    colModel: [
        { name: "PMOPerson" },
        ...
    ],
    ...
});

// make separate asynchronous Ajax request to the server and set 
//  edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: ... }
setSelectOptionValues("/Person/GetSelectData", $("#grid"), "PMOPerson");
```

The code of `setSelectOptionValues` depends on the format of JSON data which you use to communicate with URL like `"/Person/GetSelectData"`. For example if the server returns just array of strings wich should be the text and the value of options of the `<select>` then the could could be the following

```js
var setSelectOptionValues = function (getJsonUrl, myGrid, colModelColumnName) {
    $.getJSON(
        getJsonUrl,
        function (data) {
            var i, selectedOptions = '', datai, dn, colModelColumn;

            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
                if (i > 0) {
                    selectedOptions += ';';
                }
                else {
                    selectedOptions = "";
                }
                datai = data[i];

                if (typeof datai === 'string') {
                    selectedOptions += datai;
                    selectedOptions += ':';
                    selectedOptions += datai;
                }
            }
            myGrid.jqGrid("setColProp", colModelColumnName, {
                edittype: "select",
                editoptions: { value: selectedOptions }
            });
        }
    );
};
```

The setting of `editoptions.value` will be done **asynchronously** inside of `setSelectOptionValues`. So it can be that the grid will be filled before the `editoptions.value` will be set. On the other side `editoptions.value` will be used only *during editing*. The response time from `"/Person/GetSelectData"` will be typically quick enough and the value `editoptions.value` will be set *before* the user start editing. If you want be absolutely sure you can still hold `editoptions.dataUrl`. In the case `editoptions.dataUrl` will be used only if the user quickly as the server with responding on `"/Person/GetSelectData"`. You can change explicit call of

```js
setSelectOptionValues("/Person/GetSelectData", $("#grid"), "PMOPerson");
```

with getting of `colModel` using `getGridParam`, the loop through all `colModel` items and calling of `setSelectOptionValues` for all items which has `editoptions.dataUrl`.

The main restriction of the last approach: you can't use `formatter: "select"` (just `edittype: "select"` only). If you fill grid data with ids and `editoptions.value` or `formatoptions.value` provides the mapping of ids to the texts then I would recommend you to use the first approach with `beforeProcessing` callback.