# Jqgrid inline edit for selectList hits server for each row

Tags: jqgrid

```
i have set ,
editoptions: { aysnc: true, dataUrl: 'ControllerName/MethodName?__SessionKey=' + sessionkey + "&Id=" + Id, buildSelect: buildSelectFromJson, style: "width: calc(100% - 65px);",
                dataEvents: [
{
                                    type: 'change',
                                    fn: function (e) {}
}
]
}

in which buildSelectFromJson returns select list in html.
```

Now dataurl hits server for each row but my select list is same for all rows. so how can i restrict to a single hit and then use that select list for all other rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest you two alternatives:

1. the server code (responsible for the URL `ControllerName/MethodName`) can place HTTP caching header. For example `Cache-Control: private, max-age=(time in seconds)`. It will force getting the data during specified time interval from the local web browser cache.
2. You can make Ajax request to `ControllerName/MethodName` **separately** and set `editoptions.value` based on the response **instead of** usage `editoptions.dataUrl` (only if `dataUrl` is undefined the `value` will be used). See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21901410/315935) for the code example of the possible implementation. By the way you can combine the call to `ControllerName/MethodName` with the main call for filling the grid. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19427444/315935) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17410568/315935).

By the way the property `aysnc: true` which you use in `editoptions` is unknown and it will be ignored.

Comment: gr8...this works(2nd option)..but how do i add "--Select--" value with null id to the selectlist

Comment: @GiteshKothavale: **Your code** build the `value`. Look at [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17410568/315935) which I reference in my answer. It shows the code like `$self.jqGrid("setColProp", "Product", { searchoptions: { value: ":All;" + newProductValues }, editoptions: { value: newProductValues } });`. So you need just set a little different values for `editoptions.value` and `searchoptions.value`

Comment: setting searchoptions didn't worked.. but setting to editoptions: { value: ":Select;" + selectedOptions } worked..still its not allowing me to set "--Select--"

Comment: one more problem is calling setSelectOptionValues on loadcomplete not working.. and calling it after jqgrid prepare end works sometimes (not always).. so where exactly we shud call setSelectOptionValues

Comment: @abcd1234: I suggested you many variants of the implementation. `setSelectOptionValues` from [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21901410/315935) shows the simplest way which can be used for setting of `editoptions.value`. One places Ajax call directly *after* the grid is created. One will get response from the server typically *after* the user can start editing. So it will work. Other answers suggest more safe way where *the response from the server to fill the grid* contains additional information required for `editoptions.value` and `searchoptions.value`. One uses `beforeProcessing`.

Comment: @abcd1234: The second way with the usage of `setColProp` inside of `beforeProcessing` (see [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17410568/315935) and read the question of cause) is the most flexibly and it's what I would recommend you to do.

Comment: thnx Oleg...already tried calling it in beforeProcessing.. but problem still exist. In your example u r refreshing filterToolbar but i my case no such toolbar exist. The problem is sometimes grid fetches all records before  setColProp gets called else it works.

Comment: @abcd1234: You are welcome! Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. You wrote "The problem is sometimes grid fetches all records before setColProp gets called". **What is not working exactly now?** What you do now? The problem was **editing** of data, isn't so. I need to see the code to point you the place where you made something incorrect. By the way I wrote in my answer: that you need to "set `editoptions.value` based on the response instead of usage `editoptions.dataUrl` (only if `dataUrl` is undefined the value will be used)". Are you sure that no `dataUrl` exist in `colModel`?

Comment: yes... i tried $.ajax instead of getJson and set async:false... finally solved..its working now.

Comment: :m using this code on after row insert to keep entire grid in edit mode $('#' + GridId).jqGrid('editRow', rowid, true); 
This code works but it scrolls down to the last record. is there any other way to keep grid in edit form